# Obtener la ruta de un archivo enumerado en un combo list

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Quería saber si es posible obtener la ruta de un archivo el cual está enumerado en un combo. Me explico, he escrito el siguiente código para listar el nombre de los archivos de una carpeta en un combo:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("1.76");
FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles("*.bin");
comboBoxEdit1.Properties.Items.Clear();
comboBoxEdit1.Properties.Items.AddRange(files);
```

Y ahora mi pregunta es: ¿puedo obtener la dirección de dicho archivo?

No me valdría hacerlo con un case ya que quiero que se puedan introducir nuevos archivo.

Se me ocurrió obtener el nombre del objeto seleccionado y hacer una comparación con la lista de archivos que hay en la carpeta y, si coincide, obtener dicha dirección.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás utilizando el ComboBox que te viene por defecto en Visual Studio para trabajar con Windows Forms, es decir, el incluido en .NET Framework: `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox`, éste no tiene una propiedad `Properties`. Supongo que será un error al copiar el código de carga del ComboBox. Debería ser:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Windows");
FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles("*.bin");
comboBoxEdit1.Items.Clear();
comboBoxEdit1.Items.AddRange(files);
```

Si cargas de esta forma el ComboBox, la propiedad `SelectedItem` de éste te devolverá un objeto `FileInfo` con la información del elemento seleccionado. A través de la propiedad `FullName` del objeto `FileInfo` puedes acceder a la ruta completa del archivo:

```
private void comboBoxEdit1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var file = (FileInfo)comboBoxEdit1.SelectedItem;
    Debug.WriteLine(file.FullName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la propiedad Datasource

```
 DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("1.76");
        FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles("*.bin");
        comboBoxEdit1.DataSource = files;
        comboBoxEdit1.DisplayMember=nameof(FileInfo.Name);
```

El objeto selecionado sera un FileInfo , con todas sus propiedades